# Check if speaker is busy

Tags: python, python-3.x, linux, audio

How do I get the status of the speaker? Whether its busy or not? And is it possible to get the status of each speaker that I have as an output?

My main issue is with Linux, would be great if there is a cross-platform solution.

Comment: What do you mean by busy? And speaker? And status?

Comment: @PeterWood if sound is already playing

Comment: Linux knows about sound cards, not speakers.  Use aplay.

Comment: Can you be more specific?

Comment: @Kepler186 The speaker doesn't know anything. It is just given an alternating current to vibrate the magnet attached to the paper cone.